# How to print a level of a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

If we have say, a tree with a depth of 2:

```
          6        <- depth = 0
         / \
        /   \
       4     9     <- depth = 1
      / \     \
     3   5     10  <- depth = 2
```

And I only want to print the second level, so 3, 5, and 10 (in that order), how would I go about doing this? I'm using the code I wrote for my inorder traversal but I'm stuck on how to track depth of the tree and print when I'm at said depth.

```
void printLevelNodesHelper(MovieNode * curr, int level){ //helper function
  int lvl = level; //store initial value of level
  if(curr != NULL){
    printLevelNodesHelper(curr->left, level+1); 
    if(level == lvl){
      cout << "Movie: " << curr->title << " " << curr->rating << endl;
    } 
    printLevelNodesHelper(curr->right, level+1);
  }
}

void MovieTree::printLevelNodes(int k){ //k is the desired level
   MovieNode * curr = root;
   if(root == NULL){ //if the tree is empty exit it
     return;
   }
   else if(k == 0){ //print the root's title
     cout << "Movie: " << curr->title << " " << curr->rating << endl;
   }
   else{
     printLevelNodesHelper(curr, k);
   }
}
```

Here's the info for my struct and class

```
struct MovieNode{
    int ranking;
    string title;
    int year;
    float rating;

    MovieNode* left = NULL;
    MovieNode* right = NULL;

};

class MovieTree{
    private:
        MovieNode* root;

    public:
        MovieTree();
        ~MovieTree();
        void printMovieInventory();
        void addMovieNode(int ranking, std::string title, int year, float rating);
        void findMovie(std::string title);
        void queryMovies(float rating, int year);
        void averageRating();
        void printLevelNodes(int k);
};
```

Comment: hint: google "level order traversal"

Comment: For `printLevelNodes()`, there is a comment documenting what the parameter is. Could you add a similar comment to document the parameters to `printLevelNodesHelper()`? Right now I infer a different purpose when I look at the non-recursive call than when I look at the recursive calls. I don't know which purpose you intended. (Both would be useful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- As your initial call to `printLevelNodesHelper` gets the desired level as argument, it makes no sense to make recursive calls with `level+1`. Think about it: when you recur, you actually descend in the tree, coming *closer* to the desired level, so you should not increase the distance to that level, but decrease it. So you should pass `level-1`
- In `printLevelNodesHelper` the `if` condition `level == lvl` is always going to be true, because neither of these *local* variables ever change value. As from the previous point we guarantee that eventually we will get a call with `level` equal to 0, we should check for `level == 0` (and so you don't need the `lvl` variable).

Code:

```
void printLevelNodesHelper(MovieNode * curr, int level) {
  if (curr != NULL) {
    printLevelNodesHelper(curr->left, level - 1); 
    if (level == 0) {
      cout << "Movie: " << curr->title << " " << curr->rating << endl;
    } 
    printLevelNodesHelper(curr->right, level - 1);
  }
}
```

With this change, the code for `MovieTree::printLevelNodes` does not need to deal with the boundary cases of `root == NULL` or `k == 0`. Both of these are well managed in the above helper function. On the other hand, you might want to add some protection against the infinite recursion that would occur if `printLevelNodes` is called with a negative value of `k`:

```
void MovieTree::printLevelNodes(int k) {
    if (k >= 0) printLevelNodesHelper(root, k);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this comment really helped!